# How to get all tuned parameters and their associated train and validation scores?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I need to report all tuned hyperparameters in conjunction with their related performance score on the train and validation set. I do the following

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=1)

pipe = Pipeline([
     ('std', StandardScaler()),
     ('reg', MLPRegressor(random_state=1234)),
 ])
reg = MLPRegressor(random_state=1, max_iter=500)

rate = [0.01, 0.1]
l2 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.05]
size = [(5,1), (10,5,2), (10,)]
params={"reg__learning_rate_init":rate,
"reg__alpha":l2,
"reg__hidden_layer_sizes":size}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid= params, cv=4, return_train_score=True, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

result_tr =grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
result_va =grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
result = pd.DataFrame({"learn_rate": rate,
                       "regularize": l2,
                       "size": size,
                       "MSE-train":-result_tr,
                       "MSE-valid":-result_va})
```

However, since the `rate`, l2, and `size` are not of the same size as the `result_tr` and `result_va`, this error is reported:

```
    633             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    634             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 635                 raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    636 
    637             if have_dicts:

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Comment: While sklearn pipeline is used question is not about it, so please get rid of this tag. There is another approach to constructing `result` dataframe: turn dictionary `grid.cv_results_` to dataframe, form from it new dataframe by selecting interesting columns (it's alpha, learning rate, size and mean scores) and lastly rename its column names to `MSE-train`, `learn_rate`, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=1)

pipe = Pipeline([
     ('std', StandardScaler()),
     ('reg', MLPRegressor(random_state=1234)),
 ])
reg = MLPRegressor(random_state=1, max_iter=500)

rate = [0.01, 0.1]
l2 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.05]
size = [(5,1), (10,5,2), (10,)]
params={"reg__learning_rate_init":rate,
"reg__alpha":l2,
"reg__hidden_layer_sizes":size}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid= params, cv=4, return_train_score=True, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

result_tr =grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
result_va =grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
Nrate= grid.cv_results_['param_reg__learning_rate_init']
Nl2= grid.cv_results_['param_reg__alpha']
Nsize= grid.cv_results_['param_reg__hidden_layer_sizes']

result = pd.DataFrame({"learn_rate": Nrate,
                       "regularize": Nl2,
                       "size": Nsize,
                       "MSE-train":-result_tr,
                       "MSE-valid":-result_va})
```